# JQuery change function not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I have a radio button and checkbox

```
<input type='radio' name='testradiochange' id='testradiochange'> Testing Radio Change</input>

<input type='checkbox' name='acknowledge' id='acknowledge' value='acknowledge'></input>
```

I want to be notified when these buttons are selected

```
$("input[name=testradiochange]:radio").change(function () {
    alert('radio selected');    
}

$("input[name=acknowledge]:checkbox").change(function () {
    alert('checkbox selected');
 }
```

The above works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. Any idea?

Comment: Use `oninput` instead of `onchange`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of typos in your code, here are they:

```js
$("input[name=testradiochange]:radio").change(function () {
    alert('radio selected');    
}); // <= it was just }, i added ); to close the function's (

$("input[name=acknowledge]:checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // if check
     alert('checkbox selected');    
    } else {                      // if uncheck
     alert('checkbox unselected');
    }
 }); // <= it was just }, i added ); to close the function's (
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type='radio' name='testradiochange' id='testradiochange'/>Testing Radio Change</label>
<!-- inputs don't have closing tags, they are self-closing, if you want to display text next to them, use a label -->
<input type='checkbox' name='acknowledge' id='acknowledge' value='acknowledge'/>
```

Comment: Sorry about the typos but my actual code had all you mentioned. Thanks for taking your time and look ing into it. We are using jquery version 3.2.1. I tried using 2.1.1 but still it didn't work. The funny thing is its working when i am running my node app(ui in jquery) locally but as soon as it is deployed in the server, it does not work. Still looking into it